# Letter numeration ('A','B','C', etc.) from digit in PHP

Tags: php

What is the PHP function to get letter (1 char symbol), based on it position.
Like 0 position - `a`, `1st` - `b`, etc.
I tried this:

```
"a"+5
```

I was expecting `f` but I get `5` instead.

Comment: Sorry for stupid question, but google does not understand me what I want.

Comment: Uhm ... neither do i.

Comment: `$char='a'; $number = ord(strtolower($char))-64;` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert number to a letter in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601105/how-to-convert-number-to-a-letter-in-php)

Comment: I get upvoted because i dont understand a question? Not bad.

Comment: @YUNOWORK - It's not up-vote. Take it as *we agree* :)

Comment: If you're trying to provide a list as an example, the 2nd item shouldn't be "etc."

Comment: @danronmoon He gave two items then `etc`.

Comment: After 38 questions you should already know that you cannot use "doesn't work" as only explanation. It's *your* question so please don't make us work just to find what the question is. I've edited it for you this time.

Comment: @Barmar more like one and a half

Comment: He said 0 is a, 1 is b. I think the sequence is pretty obvious, especially with the title and other description in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to use [`chr()`](http://uk.php.net/chr) and/or [`ord()`](http://uk.php.net/ord) functions. Something like:

```
echo chr( ord("a") + $i );
```

Comment: Yes! thanks! chr(ord("a")+$i)

Answer (score 1):

```
$alphabet = range('a', 'z');
echo array_search('b', $alphabet); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this chr() and/or ord() functions.

Some like:

```
print chr( ord("x") + $z );
```