# How to create pagination with letters using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

**Agent controller:**

```
public function index() {
    if (!empty($_SESSION['admin'])) {
        $data = array(
            'page_title' => 'Agent',
            'page_name' => 'agent/index',
            'result' => $this->agent_model->list_all()
        );
        $this->load->view('template', $data);
    } else {
        redirect('login');
    }
}
```

**Agent model:**

```
 public function list_all() {
    $data = 'agent.id,agent.name,agent.mobile,agent.vehicle,agent.address,agent.img_url,agent.category,agent.status,agent.login_status,vehicle.id AS vehicle_id,vehicle.name AS vehicle_name';
    $this->db->select($data);
    $this->db->from('agent');
    $this->db->join('vehicle', 'agent.vehicle=vehicle.id');
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

**View:**

```
<?php foreach ($result as $value): ?>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 profile_details">
        <div class="well profile_view">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h4 class="brief"><i>Digital Strategist</i></h4>
                <div class="left col-xs-7">
                    <p><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Name: <?= $value['name']; ?></p>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><i class="fa fa-building"></i> Vehicle: <?= $value['vehicle_name']; ?></li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Mobile: <?= $value['mobile']; ?> </li><br/>
                        <div class="onoffswitch">
                            <input type="hidden" value="<?= $value["id"]; ?>"/>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch"
                            <?php if ($value['status'] == 1) {
                                echo "checked";
                            } ?>>
                        </div>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="right col-xs-5 text-center">
                    <img src="/<?= $value['img_url']; ?>" alt="" class="img-circle img-responsive" style="height: 120px; width: 120px;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 bottom text-center">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 emphasis">
                    <p class="ratings">
                        <a>4.0</a>
                        <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></a>
                        <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></a>
                        <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></a>
                        <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></a>
                        <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-star-o"></span></a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 emphasis btn-group">
                    <?php if ($value['status'] == 1): ?>
                        <a href="<?= base_url("agent/edit/{$value['id']}"); ?>" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" id="btnEdit<?= $value['id'] ?>" style="display: block;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> </i> Edit</a>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <a href="<?= base_url("agent/edit/{$value['id']}"); ?>" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" id="btnEdit<?= $value['id'] ?>" style="display: none;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> </i> Edit</a>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <a href="<?= base_url("agent/detail/{$value['id']}"); ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"> </i> View Profile </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Below Screenshot:**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE82q.jpg)

MY Question: How to create pagination with letters in codeigniter.
MY Question: I create agent module and i apply pagination with letters in above Screenshot. so how to apply pagination with letters in above view.

Comment: @parth please help me...

Comment: This might get you started https://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/

Comment: @kishankakadiya which library you are using for pagination?

Comment: $this->load->library("pagination"); i used libreary

Comment: @parth $this->load->library("pagination"); i used library

Comment: I am not sure what is your requirement, you want to convert number to alphabet? in pagination correct? and is this ci default library?

Comment: @parth but i don't know how to convert number to alphbet

Comment: @kishankakadiya check the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601105/how-to-convert-number-to-a-letter-in-php)